# clock settings on boot screen ubuntu 17.10 gnome

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, gdm

Ubuntu 17.10, gnome 3.26.1 (xorg)

If I start up my computer, it boots, and presents the login screen.  If I do NOT login, but just let it sit for a while, eventually I get a screen that shows me the time.  I then have to "swipe" that screen out of the way to see the login screen.

Regarding the screen with the clock that appears if I do not login right away:  How do I modify that clock?  Currently it is 24 hour format, I would like to change that.  (Same for the clock on the top bar on the login screen itself:  How does one change that format?)

(Note well:  I am NOT talking about the lock screen that appears AFTER I have already logged in.)

Comment: Not going to be easy: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179153/70524 Both lock screens are from GNOME Shell (one from the GDM instance and one from your instance), which has no option for configuring the time format.

Comment: hmmmm....  Thanks muru for the explanation.  Kinda sad news, but not such a big deal I guess.  Thank you again for the reply.